# How to wrangle the data using Lubridate package and Regex instead of using the separate function?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, lubridate, data-wrangling

https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows-and-movies-exploratory-analysis/data ---- contains the data set.

This is an exploratory data analysis performed on the shows from the Netflix data set. There are two main objectives in the data wrangling process. First is to get only the year part separately from the date_added column. Second is to create a new column which contains the number of seasons for a particular show from the duration column. I have relied on the `separate` function from the `dplyr` package to achieve the above two objectives.

The code is as follows:-

```
# Neitlix EDA ----
# https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows-and-movies-exploratory-analysis

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)    

net_flix <- read.csv("netflix_titles_nov_2019.csv")

net_flix_wrangled_tbl <- net_flix %>%
    separate(date_added, 
             into = c("date","month","year"),
             sep = "-",
             remove = FALSE)%>%
    separate(duration,
             into = c("count","show_type"),
             sep = " ",
             remove = FALSE)%>%
    glimpse()
```

Those who do not wish to download the data can use the following code of the data frame contained below:

```
sf <- data.frame(date_added = c("30-11-19", "29-11-19", "", "12-07-19", "", "16-09-19"), 
duration = c("1 Season", "67 min", "135 min", "2 Seasons", "107 min", "3 Seasons"))
```

The output is working with the `separate()` function for getting both the date and filtering the number of Seasons from the duration column.

But can this be done in a better and a robust way by using the `lubridate` package to get the year and `ifelse()` and `filter()` or `Regex` function to get only number of seasons and not the minutes of movies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one alternative :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


sf %>%
  mutate(date_added = dmy(date_added), 
         date = day(date_added), month = month(date_added),
         year = year(date_added), 
         count = readr::parse_number(as.character(duration)),
         show_type = stringr::str_remove(duration, as.character(count)))


#  date_added  duration date month year count show_type
#1 2019-11-30  1 Season   30    11 2019     1    Season
#2 2019-11-29    67 min   29    11 2019    67       min
#3       <NA>   135 min   NA    NA   NA   135       min
#4 2019-07-12 2 Seasons   12     7 2019     2   Seasons
#5       <NA>   107 min   NA    NA   NA   107       min
#6 2019-09-16 3 Seasons   16     9 2019     3   Seasons
```